# Is there a way to replace scanner, with the java applet mousedown boolean event?

Tags: java, applet, java.util.scanner, mousedown

beginner coder here!

```
import java.util.*;
public class TicTacToe1 {
static boolean Lose(String [][] board) {

        int win = 0;

        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[0][i].equals("O")) win++;
        }
        if(win==3) return true;

        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[1][i].equals("O")) win++;
        }
        if(win==3) return true;

        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[2][i].equals("O")) win++;
        }
        if(win==3) return true;

        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[i][0].equals("O")) win++;
            if(win==3) return true;
        }
        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[i][1].equals("O")) win++;
            if(win==3) return true;
        }
        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[i][2].equals("O")) win++;
            if(win==3) return true;
        }
        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if(board[i][i].equals("O")) win++;
            if(win==3) return true;
        }
        win = 0;
        int s =0;
        for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(board[s][i].equals("O")) win++;
            s++;
        }       
        if(win==3) return true;
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    static boolean Win(String [][] board) {

        int win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[0][i].equals("X")) win++;
        }
        if(win==3) return true;
        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[1][i].equals("X")) win++;
        }
        if(win==3) return true;
        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[2][i].equals("X")) win++;
        }
        if(win==3) return true;
        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[i][0].equals("X")) win++;
            if(win==3) return true;
        }
        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[i][1].equals("X")) win++;
            if(win==3) return true;
        }
        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
            if(board[i][2].equals("X")) win++;
            if(win==3) return true;
        }
        win = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if(board[i][i].equals("X")) win++;
            if(win==3) return true;
        }
        win = 0;
        int s = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(board[s][i].equals("X")) win++;
            s++;
        }       
        if(win==3) return true;
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean run = true;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int column;
        int userinput2;
        System.out.println("AI's Turn!");
        String [][]board=new String[][] {
                {"B","B","B"},
                {"B","O","B"},
                {"B","B","B"}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(board[i]));
        }
        int turn = 1;
        while(turn==1) {
            if(Win(board)==true) {
                System.out.println("GAME OVER! YOU WIN!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if(Lose(board)==true) {
                System.out.println("GAME OVER! YOU LOSE!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("Your Turn!");
            column= sc.nextInt();
            userinput2= sc.nextInt();
            while (board[userinput2][column] == "X" || board[userinput2][column] == "O") {
                System.out.println("This spot is occupied. Please try again");
                column= sc.nextInt();
                userinput2= sc.nextInt();
            }
            board[userinput2][column]="X";
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(board[i]));
            }
            turn*=-1;

            while (turn==-1) {
                System.out.println("AI's Turn!");
                boolean yes= false;
                boolean yes2 = false;
                int count = 0;
                if(yes==false) {
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
                        if(board[i][0].equals("X")) count++;
                        if(count==2) {
                            for(int j = 0 ; j< 3; j++ ) {
                                if((!board[j][0].equals("X"))&&(!board[j][0].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[j][0]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    int counti = 0;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
                        if(board[i][2].equals("X")) counti++;
                        if(counti==2) {
                            for(int j = 0 ; j< 3; j++ ) {
                                if((!board[j][2].equals("X"))&&(!board[j][2].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[j][2]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    int count2 = 0;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
                        if(board[0][i].equals("X")) count2++;
                        if(count2==2) {
                            for(int j = 0 ; j< 3; j++ ) {
                                if((!board[0][j].equals("X"))&&(!board[0][j].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[0][j]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    int count3 = 0;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
                        if(board[2][i].equals("X")) count3++;
                        if(count3==2) {
                            for(int j = 0; j< 3; j++ ) {
                                if((!board[2][j].equals("X"))&&(!board[2][j].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[2][j]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if((yes2==false)&&(yes==false)) {
                    int counter = 0;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
                        if(board[2][i].equals("O")) counter++;
                        if(counter==2) {
                            for(int j = 0; j< 3; j++ ) {
                                if((!board[2][j].equals("X"))&&(!board[2][j].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[2][j]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    int counter2 = 0;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
                        if(board[0][i].equals("O")) counter2++;
                        if(counter2==2) {
                            for(int j = 0 ; j< 3; j++ ) {
                                if((!board[0][j].equals("X"))&&(!board[0][j].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[0][j]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    int counter3 = 0;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
                        if(board[i][0].equals("O")) counter3++;
                        if(counter3==2) {
                            for(int j = 0 ; j< 3; j++ ) {
                                if((!board[j][0].equals("X"))&&(!board[j][0].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[j][0]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    int counter4 = 0;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
                        if(board[i][2].equals("O")) counter4++;
                        if(counter4==2) {
                            for(int j = 0 ; j< 3; j++ ) {
                                if((!board[j][2].equals("X"))&&(!board[j][2].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[j][2]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    int counter5 = 0;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< 3; i++ ) {
                        if(board[i][i].equals("O")) counter5++;
                        if(counter5==2) {
                            for(int j = 0 ; j< 3; j++ ) {
                                if((!board[j][j].equals("X"))&&(!board[j][j].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[j][j]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    int counter6=0;
                    int s = 0;
                    int s2 = 0;
                    for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (counter6==2) {
                            for(int j = 2; j >= 0; j--) {
                                if((!board[s2][j].equals("X"))&&(!board[s2][j].equals("O"))) {
                                    board[s2][j]="O";
                                    yes=true;
                                    yes2=true;
                                    break;
                                }
                                s2++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(board[s][i].equals("O"))counter6++;
                        s++;
                    }   
                }
                if((yes==false)&&(yes2==false)) {
                    if((!board[0][0].equals("O"))&&(!board[0][0].equals("X"))&&(run==true)) {
                        board[0][0]="O";
                        yes=false;
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if((!board[0][2].equals("O"))&&(!board[0][2].equals("X"))&&(run==true)) {
                        board[0][2]="O";
                        yes=false;
                        run=false;
                    } 
                    else if(!board[2][2].equals("O")&&(!board[2][2].equals("X"))&&(run==true)) {
                        board[2][2]="O";
                        yes=false;
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if(!board[2][0].equals("O")&&(!board[2][0].equals("X"))&&(run==true)) {
                        board[2][0]="O";
                        yes=false;
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else {
                        for(int i =0; i<=3;i++) {
                            if(board[i][0].equals("B")) {
                                board[i][0]="O";
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(board[i][1].equals("B")) {
                                board[i][1]="O";
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(board[i][2].equals("B")) {
                                board[i][2]="O";
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(board[0][i].equals("B")) {
                                board[0][i]="O";
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(board[1][i].equals("B")) {
                                board[1][i]="O";
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(board[2][i].equals("B")) {
                                board[2][i]="O";
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(board[i]));
                }
                turn*=-1;
                yes=false;
                run=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am in the process of trying to create a Tic Tac Toe game, and I am trying to convert this into an actual java applet, and am having trouble having the AI actually wait for the user to click on the mouse before making a move. This is presumably because scanner waits for a userinput, however the mouse down event does not. Any workaround to this?

Comment: Java applets are dead technology; see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289.  So if you are doing this to create something useful, pick an alternative.  And this is part of your coursework, your teacher really needs to update the curriculum.

Comment: The answer is: AFAIK, No - not directly.  You will need to restructure your code to make it event driven.  See the dup link.